# GDB hangs on breakpoint (using Codeblocks & CppUTest)

Tags: c++, gdb, codeblocks, cpputest

I've been using the same CodeBlocks (13.12) with the same GDB (7.5) for the same code-project for over two years now. It's a unit test project using the CppUTest framework (older than 3.4 - I think). The code is constantly changing of course - maybe that's a red herring - but maybe some change in the code caused my recent problem:

Basically since a couple of weeks - when and where ever I set a breakpoint - I get to the breakpoint alright, but then I can't move on, I can't "step over", "step into", "continue", nothing. If I try I just stay at the same line of code where the breakpoint is, and I get the associated

```
"At C:\...\myFile.cpp:83"
```

debugger output as if I ask the debugger to go to that same breakpoint again and again.

Any idea someone? I tried my best to "google" it, but no luck. :-/

EDIT: To make this more interesting this is actually not consistent behavior. I just set another breakpoint in a subroutine and now things work as expected. Then I have now added a few lines of code setting up mocking using the CppUTest and now things work again...maybe a bug in the old CppUTest framework...

EDIT2: Now in another location I can step into the subroutine but then I'm stuck at the top line of the routine. :-/

Comment: I have exactly the same using 16.01 (and 13.12). It is not repeatable sometimes does it, usually doesn't. Normally have to kill gdb and (if necessary - if cannot close it normally) code::blocks and then restart it to recover.